# Mapped network drive is behind a VPN; How do I stop Windows from auto-connecting at startup?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, network-shares

*(After about 15 minutes of searching S.U. I haven't found any relevant questions, so excuse me if I got the wrong search terms, and this is a dupe.)*

I'm running Windows 7 at work, and have a couple network drives mapped through a VPN.
(This is using the basic VPN connection tool built into Windows 7.
i.e. Where your VPN shows up with the list of wireless networks by the system tray.)
Once I get into Windows, everything works well.
I just connect to the VPN, then I can click on the network drive in Explorer and get prompted to reconnect the network drive.
This succeeds, and I go about my business.
However, the problem is that, since the VPN is not connected at startup, Windows spends a minute or two timing out, failing to connect to the network drives.
I can't get the VPNs to connect at startup, because the only answers I've found on *that* subject refer to shortcuts which do not exist in Windows 7.

#### Question:

Is there a way to stop Windows from auto-connecting the network drives on startup?
Alternately, can I change the timeout/retry time for when a network drive fails to connect?

Comment: You can drive running "net use * /delete /y". Put that in a batch script that runs at logon. You can do this with either Group Policy or Task Scheduler, or by placing it in your startup folder

Comment: It seems I never gave you the full idea. Once you do that, map the drives not persistently by using the `p:/no` switch. This means mapped drives will disconnect upon logout and not reconnect upon login.